# Converting if-else to for loop

Tags: c++, c++11

```
int max_range = 100;
// I do not want to add more else if.. Actually max range is still 100 with more else ifs.
// Range can take values from 0 to 100

if (range <= 10){
    a[0]= value;
}

else if (range > 10 && range <= 20){
    a[1]= value;
}

else if (range> 20 && range <= 30){
    a[2]= value;
}

else if (range > 30 && range <= 40){
    a[3]= value;
}

else if (range> 40 && <= max_range){
    a[4]= value;
}
```

It is simple code. I would like it to remove the nested else if's and use a for loop.
How can I convert this into a for loop?

Comment: `if`-`else` is one operation - what is your `for` loop going to loop round?

Comment: I don't really see how you could replace it with a loop. You could loop over the index into `a` I guess, but then you would still need some kind of condition for the range anyway. Would it be more readable and easier to understand? Probably not.

Comment: Changing `if` to `switch` is something I've seen, but it looks like you can make a loop that goes from `0` to `max_range / 10`. The loop value (say `i`) could be used as an index, like `if (range > i*10 && range <= i*10+10){ a[i] = value; }`.

Comment: @GolezTrol that fails if max_range is 50 or more

Comment: @Caleth Depends how the array is defined. My guess is that this is actually dynamic and OP wants his code to be dynamic too..

Comment: What is `range`? The loop counter?

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, I've seen a neat solution to this problem (with `std::lower_bound` or something) before. let me look for it.

Comment: Do you intend the values `10`, `20`, ..... `max_range` be fixed at compile time, or provided as user input?

Comment: @Peter max_range is not always fixed. provided by the user.

Comment: Do we need to be cognizant of whether `range` can be negative?

Comment: @Andy `range` is always positive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need a loop, you are doing one action.

```
a[std::max(0, std::min(4, (range - 1) / 10))] = value;
```

Comment: Yeah. It would be `(range-1)/10`. 30 would lead to 2, 20 would lead to 1. Only range=0 would go wrong, if that would be a possibility. Could optionally be coveredby adding a `max` as well.

Comment: @AndyG on balance, neither can I :p

Comment: Methinks you need a floor of 0 in there too.

Comment: And from C++17, that's a job for [`std::clamp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp) :)

Comment: Good solution, but, in few weeks, even you will have difficulties understanding what this single line of code does.

Answer (score 0):

My other answer is very particular to the boundaries being multiples of 10. A runtime modifiable version would be something like

```
std::set<int> boundaries = { 10, 20, 30, 40, max_range };

// ... potentially modify `a` and `boundaries`, keeping the number of elements equal

a[std::distance(boundaries.begin(), boundaries.lower_bound(range))] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

`I would like it to remove the nested else if's and use a for loop` Probably incorrect expression: There's no `nested if-else` in your example.

- Loops, if-else and switch work differently however they all handle conditions:

Loops do iteration; Checking for some condition `n` times whereas if, switch they check once. So you cannot convert a if-else into a loop.

- It's really a good programming trying to make the code effective and as smaller as possible but it is not always the case. If so why such experts build a huge programs with maybe millions of code lines.
- Your code works fine.